# Reading an xml response and printing a required data in python

Tags: python, utf-8, xml-parsing

I have got an xml data as a output for my code. And Now I wanted to get an element value from the obtained xml data. 
I have used following commands

```
data1 = r1.read()
       dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(data1)
       conference=dom.getElementsByTagName('totalResults')
       print conference.node value
```

But I was unable get the value.

My xml code will be

```
<first:totalresults>100</first:totalresults>
```

and so on

So now I want the value 100 to be printed
So can any one help me in solving this. I have been trying for this since last night please any one kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you'd use `etree` for an easier XML parsing :

```
from lxml import etree

myFile = open("file.xml", 'r')
tree = etree.parse(myFile)
data = tree.xpath('//ns:totalresults', namespaces={'ns': 'http://api.com'})
print data
```

Comment: Can you post the full XML file ? (so I can see what namespace you have, etc.)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<first xmlns:opensearch="http://b9.com/" xmlns="http://api.com">
  <search:Query role="request" startPage="1" searchTerms="if"/>
  <search:totalResults>1331</search:totalResults>
  <search:startIndex>0</search:startIndex>
  <search:itemsPerPage>10</search:itemsPerPage></tracks>                Now I want only the out value of serach:totalresults=1331

Comment: can you kindly reply me soon.

Comment: Edited to answer to include a reference to the namespace. Please edit your example with the whole XML by the way. On a well formed file this works for me ... Your file is weird : I don't see any opening "<tracks>" anywhere.